# How can I use "= operator" when function return? (in C++)

Tags: c++, return

I am starter of C++. When I study the opensource, I see the function.

```
int foo(int a, int b){
    return a=b;
}
```

But I only know the function return such as...

```
int foo(int a, int b){
    return a;
}
```

what is the meaning of this "return a=b" statement?

Comment: _I am starter of C._ Please, don't confuse C with C++. These are two distinct languages (though C++ evolved out of C). There are quite a lot of people in this community who are quite sensitive about this...

Comment: Btw. while `return a=b;` is valid and working -- it's complete non-sense. The compiler will hopefully eliminate the assignment from the generated code as it has no visible side effect. (`a` and `b` are value parameters. They stop to exist just after the `return`. So, there is no opportunity to do anything with the assigned `a`. `return b;` would result in the exact same outcome.)

Comment: Can you show the context in which you saw this? Also, you say "C" in thr question but your tag and title say "C++". Choose one.

Comment: Oh I edited C-> C++. Sorry for the confusion. And I understand the meaning of return a=b.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)